# xcode7 remove simulators run

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

Run destinations -> Add more simulators -> Select one of the simulators -> Uncheck Show in Run destinations … and oops - I still see it there.

How can I clean up the simulators I don't use for the project? Of course I could delete them, but I need some for other projects as well.

Comment: If you still see the device in the run destinations menu after removing that checkbox, that would be a bug.  File a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: bug successfully  reported.

Comment: what is the radar number?

Comment: problem id is 23649785, I don't know what radar number you mean or where can I find it.

Comment: that is the radar number.